# material bootstrap design is not working at React 18

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIE9x.jpg)[I have tried to install mdb-ui-kit in react version 18. is there any alternative way to install it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIE9x.jpg)

Comment: Try reducing react version to 16.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package has react 17 as a peer dependency. Try to force the installation with

```
npm i mdb-react-ui-kit -- force
```

and test if it's still working. Otherwise you can downgrade your react version to 17.